# How to make title bar buttons invisible and visible on mouseover?

Tags: window-decoration

The title bar buttons (minimize, maximize/restore and close) are normally visible at all times. I want them to be invisible all the time and visible only on mouseover.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Gnome Shell 3.4

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to make a custom theme where the buttons are not drawn unless the mouse pointer is hovering over them.

Comment: But I don't know, how to make a custom theme. I am using Adwaita (default) and I like it. Is there any easy way to edit this and make the changes what I want.